# Does Grails fork uses port 8080?

Tags: grails, grails-2.2

I tried to use the new forked option in `buildConfig.groovy`:

```
grails.project.fork = [
   run: [maxMemory:1024, minMemory:64, debug:false, maxPerm:256]
]
```

Then I started the application:

```
grails run-app
```

And tried to hit the localhost:8080/myapp, but the application don't responds.

I am missing some other configuration?

**EDIT:** Based on @c_maker's answer, I checked the process. Changing to `debug:true` and `--stacktrace` I see the message:

```
| Running Grails application
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005
```

And the process don't exit, but don't do anything else (waited 3 mins). So I don't know if this is the same as pointed in the link.

**Interesting is that stop-app says that the server was stopped but the process still exists!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like others are having similar issues with this:

http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Fork-mode-problems-td4641428.html

Looks like a genuine bug, but I could not find the JIRA on it.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I'm not sure is the same issue. Check my update.